# Swizzling and super

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to swizzle the canPerformAction:withSender: method for UIResponder and all its subclasses which have overridden this method.

I am doing this by storing the original implementations in a dictionary keyed by class name; and looking up the dictionary in the swizzled version of the implementation before calling out to the original implementation.

This seems to work fine for some cases, but fails when the original implementation calls out to super. Then my swizzled method continuously keeps getting invoked and the program gets into infinite recursion.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

After the swizzle the `-original` with `-custom`:

```
-(void)custom {
    [self custom]; // calls -original
}

-(void)original {
    [self original]; // calls -custom
}
```

Said that, if you have the methods swizzled in the superclass, objc_msgSendSuper will do the same: call original for custom and versa giving you the recursion.

---

```
-(void)custom {
    [self original]; // calls -custom, makes recursion
}

 -(void)original {
    [self custom]; // calls -original, makes recursion
}
```

Comment: My custom looks like this:

-(void) custom {

// Do something extra

[self original]
}

Original probably looks like:

-(void) original {

// Do some localized logic

[super original]

}

custom and original are swizzled only for classes which specifically override these methods in the hierarchy.

I always get into an infinite recursion of custom with the same class; never calling out to super.

Comment: @Karthik But that is only natural, see the answer again, by calling `-original` after the swizzle `-custom` is called and it has `[self original]` inside which calls `-custom` again (because of the swizzle) making the inf loop. If you want to call `-original` from inside the swizzled `-custom`, call `[self custom]`, that will do the trick.

Comment: That unfortunately does not do the trick since self still points to the base class and not the super. I got around this by using imp_implementationWithBlock. Thanks.

Comment: It seems can't run `super` but the original method is good for `canPerformAction:withSender` too.

Comment: @Karthik I have encountered the same issue. Could you explain how did you solve it with `imp_implementationWithBlock`?