# Recursive looking Swift extension func, actually isn't. Why not?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am looking at the Swift code of the [ThemeKit](https://github.com/luckymarmot/ThemeKit) theming library.

In particular I would like to understand the following code in [NSColor+ThemeKit.swift](https://github.com/luckymarmot/ThemeKit/blob/master/Sources/NSColor%2BThemeKit.swift):

```
// ThemeKit.set() replacement to use theme-aware color
@objc public func themeKitSet() {
    // call original .set() function
    themeKitSet()

    // check if the user provides an alternative color
    if ThemeManager.shared.isEnabled && isThemeOverriden {
        // call ThemeColor.set() function
        ThemeColor.color(with: Selector(colorNameComponent)).set()
    }
}
```

There is what appears to be an endless recursive call, but presumably can't be, since the code works fine. This is confirmed by setting a breakpoint on the call to `themeKitSet()`. It is not possible to step into the call and execution continues without recursion.

Earlier in the file there is the following call:

```
swizzleInstanceMethod(cls: NSClassFromString("NSDynamicSystemColor"), selector: #selector(set), withSelector: #selector(themeKitSet))
```

With the implementation in [NSObject+ThemeKit.swift](https://github.com/luckymarmot/ThemeKit/blob/master/Sources/NSObject%2BThemeKit.swift) as follows:

```
/// Swizzle instance methods.
@objc internal class func swizzleInstanceMethod(cls: AnyClass?, selector originalSelector: Selector, withSelector swizzledSelector: Selector) {
    guard cls != nil else {
        print("Unable to swizzle \(originalSelector): dynamic system color override will not be available.")
        return
    }

    // methods
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, swizzledSelector)

    // add new method
    let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(cls, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod!))

    // switch implementations
    if didAddMethod {
        class_replaceMethod(cls, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod!))
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
    }
}
```

I suspect this is responsible for the magic, but my limited understanding of both Swift and Objective-C is letting me down.

What is happening here? Why is the apparently recursive call not actually recursive?

Comment: It calls the *original* implementation, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13294420/1187415.

Comment: This is why I never liked method swizzling. Even if you had no other choice but to change method implementations at runtime, I think it's way better to do so by binding to new selectors. If these methods were called `modifiedThemeKitSet` (whose IMPL was set as the IMPL for `themKitSet`), and `originalThemeKitSet` (whose IMPL is the original IMPL for `themKitSet`), then none of this confusion would have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly identified the magic bit: it's called method swizzling, and it's a way of wholesale replacing an existing method implementation.

You'll see this seemingly-recursive pattern a lot when method swizzling: that `themeKitSet` call actually runs the original implementation, as the comment says. It's because swizzling *swaps* the implementations of two methods, in this case `themeKitSet` and `NSDynamicSystemColor.set`.

Therefore, post-swizzle, `NSDynamicSystemColor.set` runs the code you see there, and `themeKitSet` has become the original implementation.